# Can Cubeworld Alpha be played offline like Minecraft Alpha

Tags: cube-world

When i got Minecraft when it was in Alpha i was glad that apart from having to connect to the internet to get the majority of the game and update it i could just copy the files to my gaming pc and play it offline (since i don't have her connect to the internet)

so i am wondering, can Cubeworld be played offline in a similar fashion to Minecraft (copy all the files to another computer) and play it just fine, i'd like to know before i commit to buying a copy as the i doubt the laptop i connect to the net would be able to play it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [system requirements for Cube World](https://picroma.com/cubeworld#overview) say it only needs an internet connection for updates and online multiplayer.